# React App Not Loading - Stuck on Loading Screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, localhost

I'm developing a web application on MacOS using Node.js, Express, MongoDB, and React. I've set up my backend server and frontend React app on different ports (3001 and 3002 respectively). When I start both servers, they seem to run without any errors. However, when I try to access my React app in the browser at http://localhost:3002, the page just keeps loading indefinitely and never actually loads the app.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Checked the console in my browser's developer tools for errors - no issues found.
Checked the network tab in developer tools - no issues found.
Checked my server logs - no errors.
Checked my system resources (CPU and Memory) - both are normal.
Cleared my browser cache and tried a hard refresh.
Reinstalled my node modules.
Despite all this, the issue persists. I'm not sure what else to try at this point. Does anyone have any suggestions for what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you share your express server source codes?